# Creating a list of incomplete task in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a live list of all incomplete from my current excel file. 
Each week is a new tab such as Week of Feb 6, Week of Feb 13, Week of Feb 20 and so on. Each of these tab has a running list of task that will be marked as open or close. The goal is to have all the task that are marked as open appear in a separate named "Open Items".

How could I program my excel sheet to create live list of all the items marked as "Open". I have tried using and if statement, but I can't figure out how to move the entire row to the "Open Items" tab.
Thank You

Comment: Question is too broad. Provide any attempted code to this point and a specific issue that causes it to fail.

Comment: I have tried using and if statement, but I can't figure out how to move the entire row to the "Open Items" tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
Sub main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, openWs As Worksheet

    Set openWs = Worksheets("Open Items") '<--| be sure you already have a sheet named after "Open Items"
    For Each ws In Worksheets '<--| loop through worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Open Items" Then '<--| if current sheet isn't named after "Open Items"
            With ws
                With .Range("C3", .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column AE range from row 1 (header) down to the one corresponding to last column A not empty row
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Open" '<--| filter column C cells with "Open" content
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<-_| if any filtered cell found other than headers
                        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 7).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy openWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| '<--| copy filtered cell (skipping headers) and paste then from "Open Items" sheet column A first empty cell after last not empty one
                    End If
                End With
                .AutoFilterMode = False
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great. How would I be able to change the range of the row that's copied. Currently it copies everything after the "Open" cell, but I would also like to include the priority and dates columns.

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your question please mark answer as accepted. Thank you. As for the range "widening" you just act on `Offset(, nColOffset)` (specifying `ncolOffset` column offset - it can be a negative number) and `Resize(, nColResize)` (specifying `nColResize` column resizing - only positive values) parameters

Comment: I cant seem to locate Offset(, nColOffset) or Resize(, nColResize).

Comment: `Offset(, nColOffset)` and `Resize(, nColResize)` were two "parametric" _examples_ of a possible use of `Offset()` and `Resize()` methods, The code already defines the working range as `.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 7)`: if you want to stretch it and have it, say, begin 1 column to the left and span, say, 10 columns, than you'd code `.Offset(1,-1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 10)`

Comment: Awesome it works!!!!! The one thing I ran into is when I try to move over the date column I get an error. I tried going through each page and un-merge the cell, but I still get the error.

Comment: It's because that column has _merged_ cells. and whenever you either write or speak of _merged_ cells you have to be frightened a lot!

Comment: I un-merged all the cells and went though and put the correct date in each line, but I still get error 400.

Comment: Figured it out. For some reason I couldn't use the first column.